# Redirecting Input File to GProlog

Tags: linux, prolog

I'm attempting to send a set of queries to gprolog through a text file, using IO redirection. The file, input.txt looks something to the effect of:

```
consult(rules).
dog(X).
halt.
```

Whenever I redirect this text file to gprolog at the command line via `gprolog < input.txt`, my terminal blows up with the repeating line `Action (; for next solution, a for all solutions, RET to stop) ?`

I've tried inserting a carriage return/newline character in between `dog(X).` and `halt.`, but that does not seem to have any effect. Suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only one solution, try:

```
consult(rules).
dog(X), !.
halt.
```

If you want all of them:

```
consult(rules).
findall(X, dog(X), List).
halt.
```

Comment: Awesome, your solution resolved my issue. Thanks so much! I would vote your response upward, but my rep isn't quite there yet :/

Comment: @JohnRuffer: You should accept the answer then. Click on the check to the left of question' text.